# Building a To-Do List with vba in excel: How to insert rows dynamically?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

First of all: I'm really sorry if this has been answered before. I've looked and found nothing that quite helped me. I'm a newbie and very grateful for any help.

My problem : I have a sheet with projects that all have individual IDs, and another sheet with tasks that have also have individual Task-ID's and the ID of the project they belong to. There are some tasks belonging to a project.

What I want to do is automatically sorting the tasks under the project they belong to, similar to a normal to-do list.

[Here is an imgur gallery of example pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSSdw.jpg)

Again, any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It's correct to assume that the Projects and the Tasks sheet will be sorted by ProjectID?

Comment: Yes, ProjectID is the main identifier of interest for both. Thanks for the answer

Comment: You are welcome, I'll post the code in minutes

Comment: You're helping me a lot with this. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with a double loop to process both worksheets (Projects and Tasks) this way:

```
    Public Sub DoResults()
    Set P = Sheets("Projects")
    Set T = Sheets("Tasks")
    Set R = Sheets("Result")

    Dim row_p, row_t, row_r As Integer
    Dim curr_project_id


    row_p = 2
    row_t = 2
    row_r = 2

    R.UsedRange.ClearContents

    While (P.Range("A" & row_p) <> "")
        curr_project_id = P.Range("A" & row_p)

        'Copy the project row in the Results Sheet
        P.Range("A" & row_p & ":C" & row_p).Copy R.Range("A" & row_r)
        row_r = row_r + 1

        While (T.Range("A" & row_t) = curr_project_id)
            T.Range("B" & row_p & ":D" & row_p).Copy R.Range("D" & row_r)
            row_t = row_t + 1
            row_r = row_r + 1
        Wend
        row_p = row_p + 1
    Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: You're crazy. It worked. You can't believe how much you help me with this. Thanks!!!

Comment: I'm really happy it worked for you! You are welcome and have a nice day!

Comment: You have one as well :)